# Comparar 2 objectos EF/2 Formularios para saber que cambio MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tengo un modal que es un `form` en el cual capturo y guardo X información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La misma pasa a un controlador:

**CONTROLADOR**

```
//AGREGA DATOS NUEVO
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public string AddEditDataExportacion(string usuario)
        {
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            long id = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.Params["id"]);
            string oo = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["oo"]);
            string pp = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["pp"]);
            string po = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["po"]);
            int cc = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["cc"]);
            int bb = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["bb"]);
            int? bc = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["bc"]);
            decimal? pb = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Request.Params["pb"]);
            decimal? pn = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Request.Params["pn"]);
            int? te = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["te"]);
            string dt = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["dt"]);
            DateTime fs = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.Params["fs"]);
            int vi = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["vi"]);
            string so = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["so"]);
            string ap = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["ap"]);
            int es = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["es"]);

            if (id == 0) //AGREGA
            {
                DateTime fc = DateTime.Now;
                string resp = exportacion.AgregaExportacion(fc, oo, pp, po, cc, bb, bc, pb, pn, te, dt, fs,  vi, so, ap, es, Session["usuario"].ToString());
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);
            }
            else
            {
                return "OK";
            }
        }
```

y esta pasa a un modelo:

**MODELO**

```
 //AGREGA EXPORTACION
        public string AgregaExportacion(DateTime? Fc, string Oo, string Pp, string Po, int Cc, int Bb, int? Bc,
                                        decimal? Pb, decimal? Pn, int? Te, string Dt, DateTime Fs,  int Vi, string So,
                                        string Ap, int Es, string userX)
        {

            try
            {
                var lista = new Exportacion
                {
                    FechaCreacion = Fc,
                    Orden = Oo,
                    Bolsas = Bb,
                    Cajas = Cc,
                    N_Parte = Pp,
                    PO = Po,
                    BolsaXCaja = Bc,
                    PesoBruto = Pb,
                    PesoNeto = Pn,
                    Tarimas = Te,
                    DimensionTarimas = Dt,
                    FechaSalida = Fs,
                    Transporte = Vi,
                    Estado = Es,
                    UsuarioCreador = userX
                };

                using (var ctx = new ModelContextSAG())
                {
                    ctx.Entry(lista).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
               
            }
            
        }
```

Resulta que yo tengo una tabla donde guardo los cambios y digo que campo fue editado, asi como su valor antiguo y nuevo (esta se utiliza en otra vista donde no hay formularios si no una tabla> fila que se puede editar por columna):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí viene mi duda, hay alguna manera de comparar de manera sencilla el `FormData` o los objectos `EF`, para saber que campo esta diferente, teniendo que consideración que cuando edite, voy a recibir esto mismo para pasarlo al modelo:

```
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            long id = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.Params["id"]);
            string oo = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["oo"]);
            string pp = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["pp"]);
            string po = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["po"]);
            int cc = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["cc"]);
            int bb = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["bb"]);
            int? bc = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["bc"]);
            decimal? pb = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Request.Params["pb"]);
            decimal? pn = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Request.Params["pn"]);
            int? te = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["te"]);
            string dt = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["dt"]);
            DateTime fs = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.Params["fs"]);
            int vi = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["vi"]);
            string so = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["so"]);
            string ap = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["ap"]);
            int es = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["es"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, hay una manera. Lo que pasa es que tú estás haciendo TODO de la forma difícil.

**1.- Constructor con inyección de dependencia**

Este paso es opcional, pero es la mejor manera de hacer y es la estándar. El **contexto** de la base de datos se pasa al **controlador**, mediante inyección de dependencia

```
public class MiControladorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ModelContextSAG db;
    public LineamientosController(ModelContextSAG db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
```

**2.- La función (el `action`) recibe un objeto**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddEditDataExportacion(Exportacion exportacion)
{
```

Si tu formulario está bien seteado, esto es con los atributos "name" bien puestos, o mejor aún si has usado las herramientas que da Razor para crear formularios, .net se encargará automáticamente se deserializar el formulario y convertiro el objeto. De esta manera **NO** es necesario todo esto:

```
HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
long id = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.Params["id"]);
string oo = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["oo"]);
// El resto de estas cosas
```

**3.- El Update**

La función debería ser algo como esto:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddEditDataExportacion(Exportacion exportacion)
{
   db.Upadte(exportacion);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return algo_que_no_se_que_es;
}
```

Si, eso es todo!!! Entity Framework se encargará solo de evaluar los campos actualizados

*Nota: Hay otra manera que es cambiando el estado del objeto: `db.Entry(exportacion).State = EntityState.Modified;`*

**4.- Agregando validaciones**

Como nada en la vida es tan perfecto, en la práctica hay que validar

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddEditDataExportacion(Exportacion exportacion)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return informamos_error_depende_de_lo_que_tu_retornes;
  }
  db.Upadte(exportacion);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return algo_que_no_se_que_es;
}
```

ModelState.IsValid entregará verdadero o falso dependiendo de los datos. Que evalúa??

- Si hay datos nulos o no. Por ejemplo tú tienes una propiedad que no acepta nulos y le enviaste un nulo, dará invalido
- Validaciones configuradas con Fluent
- Validaciones configuradas con DataAnnotations

Por ejemplo en esta última, tu modelo puede ser (inventaré campos):

```
public class Exportacion 
{
   [Required]
   public string Codigo { get; set; }

   [Range(2, 100)]
   public int Nivel { get; set; }

   [StringLength(22)]
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Y por supuesto puedes crear las validaciones propias.